# How to update object attributes values in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout.js so...

I've got an object:

```
function My_editor()
{
    this.brushSize = 10;
    this.activeColor = '#ff0000';
};
var editor = new My_editor();
```

It is some sort or drawing tool.
Here's the Knockout View-Model:

```
function AppViewModel(ed)
{
    this.brushSize = ko.observable(ed.brushSize);
    this.activeColor = ko.observable(ed.activeColor);
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(editor));
```

I've written some html interface and it works OK.
**The problem is that if I change the brushSize value via Knockout it doesn't change the corresponding attribute of the editor object.** I'm using Google Chrome developer tools to inspect my object's state.

Piece of html:

```
<p>Brush Size: <input type="number" data-bind="value: brushSize" /></p>
<p>Active Color: <input type="color" data-bind="value: activeColor" /></p>
```

Also, if I change brushSize in console, it doesn't update in the interface & knockout.
I'm using:

```
editor.brushSize = 15;
```

Comment: What does the HTML that you are binding this to look like?

Comment: several simple input fields... i've updated the question post!

Comment: What does your `afterkeydown` callback look like?

Comment: actually, the input fields were previously just a text-fields. so, ignore it. it's an ordinary onKeyDown event. i fixed the question post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, accidentally, I've found the simplest solution: **Extenders** (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).

I need to add something like that before AppViewModel:

```
ko.extenders.updateEditor = function(target, option)
{
  target.subscribe(function(newValue)
  {
    //console.log(option,newValue);
    editor[option] = newValue;
  });
  return target;
};
```

... and modify the AppViewModel like that:

```
this.brushSize = ko.observable(ed.brushSize).extend({ updateEditor: 'brushSize' });
this.activeColor = ko.observable(ed.activeColor).extend({ updateEditor: 'activeColor' });
```

Voila! The 'editor' object attributes are correctly updated now!
Thanks everyone for participating.

Answer (score 0):

Your values are being copied, a reference to the original editor object isn't being stored.

You are using value types when using `strings` and `int`.  Since you pass the editor object it and access the values from it directly, your vm and `knockout` are copying the values, not a reference to the editor object.

I would say you should use the vm to do all your work and if you want to access data, pull it from the vm.  If you needed to save the data, then I would pull the data from the vm into another object and pass it to the server.

If you provide a little more detail on what you are trying to accomplish, I would be able to better provide an example.

Comment: I want to update "editor.brushSize" =) via interface. As far as I understand, knockout updates values in the instance of the AppViewModel. Do I have to write my own setters to update the original editor fields? Where is the synchronization provided by knockout?

Comment: the thing is that My_editor() consists of a dozen of attributes and methods, that already allow me to draw. Now I want to build a UI for it, so that I can change the brushSize not by typing editor.brushSize=15 in the console, but changing the value using html-sliders...

Comment: `Knockout` offers the synchronization by `ko.observable`.  You could write your own setters, but does the `editor` object offer anything that you can't just put into the vm?  The vm is all the stuff needed to make the current view work.  See my update if you REALLY want to keep using the editor object.

Comment: I don't want to mess my completely independent object with something from another library/framework (I've written it in pure JS). I've found the solution, see my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27770842/967024

Comment: If you want to use the benefits of KO, you will have to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses:

editor.brushSize(15);

Comment: doesn't work. editor is not a knockout object, and it has no method called brushSize. read carefully.

Comment: Changes to editor will not be picked up by knockout, it has no way of knowing when the object has changed. You need to go through the view model as shown above. If you really need to take the approach you are taking look at ko.mapping.fromJS(); to update your view model when you have changed editor.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, when using knockout, it's best if you use "observables all the way down"; i.e. if all your objects you want to see live-updates for use observables for properties.

```
function My_editor()
{
    this.brushSize = ko.observable(10);
    this.activeColor = ko.observable('#ff0000');
};
var editor = new My_editor();
```

Then in your AppViewModel:

```
function AppViewModel(ed)
{
//Either this:        
    this.brushSize = ed.brushSize; //The editor's observables are shared between both ViewModels
    this.activeColor = ed.activeColor;

//OR  (my preference)
    this.editor = ed;
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(editor));
```

Personally, I prefer the second approach so you can freely add properties to the editor ViewModel without needing to add more code to the AppViewModel.

If you can't, or don't want to make the `My_Editor` viewModel's properties observables, you might have to find a way to manually trigger updates when the VM changes, (i.e. when you set `editor.brushSize = 15`, you'd call a line of code that causes the AppViewModel's observables to update) but that's pretty hacky and isn't really utilizing KO properly, so I'd really suggest make the `My_editor` observable.

Comment: What if I list all the attributes I want to sync, like brushSize & activeColor. Is there any way I can update my object "editor" with the new values from AppViewModel?

Comment: Can extended observables help me? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

Comment: You could use a subscription to update the Editor when you change the AppViewModel... but it's *much* harder to get your AppViewModel to update when your editor changes, which is what you're trying to do, as I can tell, without making the `My_editor` properties observable.

Comment: What's your reason for *not* making the `My_editor` properties observable?  Why go to all the hassle of extenders, to get an inferior result (one-way binding, rather than two-way)

Comment: Don't want to mess the pure JS code with third-party libraries/frameworks. And I don't need the binding from My_editor -> to AppViewModel, actually. Extenders seem to satisfy my needs.